# Knockout validation extend 'required only if' with observable parameter

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there a way to extend an observable to make it required only if and observable is true, and that changes can be tracked?

For example, I got this custom extender:

```
ko.extenders.requiredOnlyIf = function (target, makeRequired) {
target.HasError = ko.observable();

function validate(newValue) {
    if (makeRequired) {
        target.HasError(newValue ? false : true);
    } else {
        target.HasError(false);
    }
}

   validate(target());
   target.subscribe(validate);
   return target;
}
```

And this observables:

```
self.Field1 = ko.observable().extend({ requiredOnlyIf : self.Field2() });
self.Field2 = ko.observable().extend({ requiredOnlyIf : self.Field1() });
```

This observables are dependant, so, if one is filled, the other must be filled too. But the extender only works fine when the value is binding the first time, but when the value of any of the observables is changed is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You need to pass the observables, not the observables' contents, when setting up the extensions. (You can't create Field1 based on Field2 before Field2 exists, either.)
2. You need two subscriptions, so that if a change to one makes the *other* invalid, that is noticed.
3. (update) Rather than subscriptions and an observable, you can use a computed

```js
ko.extenders.requiredOnlyIf = function(target, makeRequired) {
  target.HasError = ko.pureComputed(() => {
    const otherHasValue = !!makeRequired();
    const targetHasValue = !!target();

    return otherHasValue && !targetHasValue;
  });

  return target;
}

self = {};

self.Field1 = ko.observable();
self.Field2 = ko.observable().extend({
  requiredOnlyIf: self.Field1
});
self.Field1.extend({
  requiredOnlyIf: self.Field2
});

ko.applyBindings(self);
```

```css
.invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="value: Field1, css: {invalid: Field1.HasError()}" />
<input data-bind="value: Field2, css: {invalid: Field2.HasError()}" />
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for!! Thank you for tell me about the subscription too, in some way, I knew that I have to subscribe, but don't know how. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just realized that should be a computed. Code updated.